# True color (RGB) is not created with Landsat5(TM) images

Tags: qgis, raster, google-earth-engine, landsat

The true color (RGB) is not created with the Landsat5 image.

I downloaded the TM video of Landsat5 from the USGS (earth explorer). I have videos from 1985 and 1986.
"LT05_L2SP_114034_19850820_20200918_02_T1"
"LT05_L2SP_114034_19860823_20200918_02_T1"

Both videos are Level2, Tier2, and Collection2.

Using QGIS, we made RGB (True Color) images by combining B3 (Red), B2 (Green), and B1 (Blue) bands of the two images, and the 1985 image was normally made, but the 1986 image was dark and yellow, and the True Color was not made. Why is the 1986 video weird when we used the same dataset and combined the same band?

[1985]
[image]

[1986]
[image]

Comment: can you share the image visualization parameters from qgis. Most likely they are not they same because QGIS automatically computes the image stretch for each band based on statistics. I would recommend going through some basic tutorials if you just started with multiband images: https://blogs.fu-berlin.de/reseda/visualize-in-qgis/

Comment: Comapre reflectance values for both scenes. And image representation is that, just a representation. QGIS automatically sets min and max for image representation. You should manually set bands, min, max and stretch for both images and then compare it